# Getting tiles from own Tilestache server to Openlayers application

Tags: openlayers-2, tilestache

The title sums up my current problem  -

1. I have installed and set Tilestache in our webserver and the tiles are accessible in browser
2. My developer is working on an application to overlay some custom layers in  kml format , over some basemap. We were using a basemap from Openlayers example, but now want to replace the url with tiles from the Tilestache.

Which method we have to get the tiles ? XYZ ? UTF grids ? httprequest ? Experts please guide..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TileStache URLs are based on a simplified TMS scheme. And Openlayers has a special Layer class to use these tiles, called [OpenLayers.Layer.TMS](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/TMS-js.html)

Have a look at [this sample](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/tms.html) which shows the usage of a TMS Layer.